# htaccess code for blocking bots is not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to block some of these below listed bots using htaccess, and its not working.

In my PHP code, I track hits from unique bots, and log useragent of bots which passed through the htaccess block.
That is how I got this list below.

I assume that anything blocked by htaccess will not trigger the PHP script, is that right?

Bots:

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; BLEXBot/1.0; +http://webmeup-crawler.com/)

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)

```
HTAccess code:

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SemrushBot" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "semrush" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "BLEXBot" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is htaccess not blocking these?

Comment: What other directives do you have in `.htaccess`? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled? In isolation, those directives should block the request as required (assuming `HTAccess code:` is not part of the code block? And the filename is spelt `.htaccess`, not `HTAccess`?). Although it's not strictly correct as written, as you are missing the corresponding `Order` directive and there is no need to repeat the `Deny` directive. You may have a conflict with other directives. Also, `Deny` is deprecated on Apache 2.4, which is more likely to be the version you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. No, "HTACCESS CODE" is not part of the .htaccess file. So on apache 2, how should I block these bots? Could you please post the correct htaccess code in the answer? Thanks

Comment: "So on apache 2" - 2.2 or 2.4? Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: Hi, yes, I got other rules in .htaccess file, those are working fine (redirect etc). Only this "block bots" is not working. This is the one I need help with. I think I got apache 2.2, but I'm not sure, could be apache 2.4 as well. No, I do not have access to server config files. Thanks